# Program consumed memory keeps growing while using PyCurl in multi threaded environment

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pycurl

Python program consumed memory grows over time when PyCurl is used in multi-threaded environment for concurrent HTTP API calls.

Attached Python code snippet demonstrates the problem.
Program simply hit URLs in multiple threads using PyCurl and logs memory usage after every iteration.

#### Code

```py
'''
Run pycurl in multi-threaded environment and log memory usage.
'''

import os
import io
import sys
import time
import logging
import itertools
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

import pycurl
import psutil

# Number of threads for concurrent HTTP calls
THREAD_COUNT = 100

# URLs for testing
URLS = [x.strip() for x in open('urls.txt') if x.strip()]
URLS = itertools.cycle(URLS)

# Setup logger
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('TestPyCURL')
CONSOLE_HANDLER = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(message)s'
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT, '%b %d %I:%M:%S')
CONSOLE_HANDLER.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
CONSOLE_HANDLER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOGGER.addHandler(CONSOLE_HANDLER)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


# Note current memory usage of program
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
last_usage = process.memory_info().rss
def log_memory_usage():
    '''
    Log change in memory usage of process.
    '''
    global last_usage
    usage = process.memory_info().rss
    change = usage - last_usage
    change_prcnt = change / last_usage * 100
    if usage == last_usage:
        slope = 'No change'
    elif usage > last_usage:
        slope = 'Increased'
    else:
        slope = 'Decreased'
    last_usage = usage
    LOGGER.info('Memory usage: Total: %s MB Change: %s, %s KB, %.3f %%',
                usage / 1000000, slope, change / 1000, change_prcnt)


def curl_request(url):
    '''
    Do HTTP request using Curl.
    '''
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
    curl.setopt(curl.TIMEOUT, 10)
    curl.setopt(curl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEDATA, buffer)
    try:
        curl.perform()
    except pycurl.error as exce:
        status = str(exce)
    else:
        status_code = curl.getinfo(curl.RESPONSE_CODE)
        status = status_code, len(buffer.getvalue())
    LOGGER.info('%s, %s', url, status)
    curl.close()
    buffer.close()


def main():
    '''
    Test pycurl.
    '''
    # Create pool of worker threads
    pool = ThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT)
    # Run forever
    while True:
        # Log change in memory usage of program
        log_memory_usage()
        # Sleep
        time.sleep(5)
        # Launch parallel HTTP requests
        urls = [next(URLS) for _ in range(0, THREAD_COUNT)]
        pool.map(curl_request, urls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

#### Test Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Python: 3.8.10
- PyCurl and LibCurl: PycURL/7.44.1 libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3

Memory usage over time logged by test program

```
Dec 17 05:30:02 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 32.17408 MB Change: Increased, 14008.32 KB, 77.114 %
Dec 17 05:30:17 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 34.28352 MB Change: Increased, 2109.44 KB, 6.556 %
Dec 17 05:30:33 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 104.075264 MB Change: Increased, 69791.744 KB, 203.572 %
Dec 17 05:30:43 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 124.370944 MB Change: Increased, 20295.68 KB, 19.501 %
Dec 17 05:30:53 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 130.592768 MB Change: Increased, 6221.824 KB, 5.003 %
Dec 17 05:31:08 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 137.158656 MB Change: Increased, 6565.888 KB, 5.028 %
Dec 17 05:31:18 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 139.640832 MB Change: Increased, 2482.176 KB, 1.810 %
Dec 17 05:31:25 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 143.33952 MB Change: Increased, 3698.688 KB, 2.649 %
Dec 17 05:31:40 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 145.32608 MB Change: Increased, 1986.56 KB, 1.386 %
Dec 17 05:31:51 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 149.516288 MB Change: Increased, 4190.208 KB, 2.883 %
....
Dec 17 05:54:17 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.025792 MB Change: Decreased, -81.92 KB, -0.031 %
Dec 17 05:54:27 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.050368 MB Change: Increased, 24.576 KB, 0.009 %
Dec 17 05:54:39 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.087232 MB Change: Increased, 36.864 KB, 0.014 %
Dec 17 05:54:54 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.935104 MB Change: Increased, 847.872 KB, 0.325 %
Dec 17 05:55:10 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.869568 MB Change: Decreased, -65.536 KB, -0.025 %
Dec 17 05:55:25 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.55008 MB Change: Decreased, -319.488 KB, -0.122 %
Dec 17 05:55:40 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.844992 MB Change: Increased, 294.912 KB, 0.113 %
Dec 17 05:55:50 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.853184 MB Change: Increased, 8.192 KB, 0.003 %
Dec 17 05:56:00 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.709824 MB Change: Decreased, -143.36 KB, -0.055 %
Dec 17 05:56:15 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 261.91872 MB Change: Increased, 208.896 KB, 0.080 %
....
Dec 17 06:18:22 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.809792 MB Change: Increased, 8.192 KB, 0.003 %
Dec 17 06:18:34 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.850752 MB Change: Increased, 40.96 KB, 0.013 %
Dec 17 06:18:44 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.711488 MB Change: Decreased, -139.264 KB, -0.044 %
Dec 17 06:19:00 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.67872 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.010 %
Dec 17 06:19:13 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.826176 MB Change: Increased, 147.456 KB, 0.047 %
Dec 17 06:19:19 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.744256 MB Change: Decreased, -81.92 KB, -0.026 %
Dec 17 06:19:25 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 315.793408 MB Change: Increased, 49.152 KB, 0.016 %
Dec 17 06:19:41 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 323.272704 MB Change: Increased, 7479.296 KB, 2.368 %
Dec 17 06:19:51 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 323.416064 MB Change: Increased, 143.36 KB, 0.044 %
Dec 17 06:20:06 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 323.293184 MB Change: Decreased, -122.88 KB, -0.038 %
....
Dec 17 06:43:19 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.764416 MB Change: Increased, 20.48 KB, 0.006 %
Dec 17 06:43:30 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.707072 MB Change: Decreased, -57.344 KB, -0.017 %
Dec 17 06:43:45 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 345.001984 MB Change: Increased, 294.912 KB, 0.086 %
Dec 17 06:43:55 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.870912 MB Change: Decreased, -131.072 KB, -0.038 %
Dec 17 06:44:05 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.887296 MB Change: Increased, 16.384 KB, 0.005 %
Dec 17 06:44:18 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.94464 MB Change: Increased, 57.344 KB, 0.017 %
Dec 17 06:44:28 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 345.018368 MB Change: Increased, 73.728 KB, 0.021 %
Dec 17 06:44:39 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.977408 MB Change: Decreased, -40.96 KB, -0.012 %
Dec 17 06:44:54 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.928256 MB Change: Decreased, -49.152 KB, -0.014 %
Dec 17 06:45:04 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 344.879104 MB Change: Decreased, -49.152 KB, -0.014 %
....
Dec 17 07:08:09 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.01152 MB Change: Increased, 3289.088 KB, 0.912 %
Dec 17 07:08:24 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.044288 MB Change: Increased, 32.768 KB, 0.009 %
Dec 17 07:08:39 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.191744 MB Change: Increased, 147.456 KB, 0.041 %
Dec 17 07:08:54 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.232704 MB Change: Increased, 40.96 KB, 0.011 %
Dec 17 07:09:05 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.208128 MB Change: Decreased, -24.576 KB, -0.007 %
Dec 17 07:09:19 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.249088 MB Change: Increased, 40.96 KB, 0.011 %
Dec 17 07:09:29 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.191744 MB Change: Decreased, -57.344 KB, -0.016 %
Dec 17 07:09:44 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.158976 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.009 %
Dec 17 07:09:54 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.126208 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.009 %
Dec 17 07:10:10 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 364.101632 MB Change: Decreased, -24.576 KB, -0.007 %
....
Dec 17 07:33:08 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.379648 MB Change: Increased, 49.152 KB, 0.013 %
Dec 17 07:33:23 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.477952 MB Change: Increased, 98.304 KB, 0.026 %
Dec 17 07:33:30 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.46976 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 07:33:36 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.453376 MB Change: Decreased, -16.384 KB, -0.004 %
Dec 17 07:33:51 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.330496 MB Change: Decreased, -122.88 KB, -0.033 %
Dec 17 07:34:07 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.30592 MB Change: Decreased, -24.576 KB, -0.007 %
Dec 17 07:34:22 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.256768 MB Change: Decreased, -49.152 KB, -0.013 %
Dec 17 07:34:37 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.215808 MB Change: Decreased, -40.96 KB, -0.011 %
Dec 17 07:34:47 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.269056 MB Change: Increased, 53.248 KB, 0.014 %
Dec 17 07:34:59 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.310016 MB Change: Increased, 40.96 KB, 0.011 %
....
Dec 17 07:56:53 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.55168 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 07:57:03 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.617216 MB Change: Increased, 65.536 KB, 0.018 %
Dec 17 07:57:13 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.453376 MB Change: Decreased, -163.84 KB, -0.044 %
Dec 17 07:57:21 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.59264 MB Change: Increased, 139.264 KB, 0.037 %
Dec 17 07:57:28 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.617216 MB Change: Increased, 24.576 KB, 0.007 %
Dec 17 07:57:44 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.584448 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.009 %
Dec 17 07:57:54 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.46976 MB Change: Decreased, -114.688 KB, -0.031 %
Dec 17 07:58:00 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.461568 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 07:58:07 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.424704 MB Change: Decreased, -36.864 KB, -0.010 %
Dec 17 07:58:22 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.359168 MB Change: Decreased, -65.536 KB, -0.018 %
....
Dec 17 08:21:03 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.699136 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 08:21:14 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.764672 MB Change: Increased, 65.536 KB, 0.018 %
Dec 17 08:21:25 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.690944 MB Change: Decreased, -73.728 KB, -0.020 %
Dec 17 08:21:35 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.994048 MB Change: Increased, 303.104 KB, 0.081 %
Dec 17 08:21:50 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.87936 MB Change: Decreased, -114.688 KB, -0.031 %
Dec 17 08:22:00 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.805632 MB Change: Decreased, -73.728 KB, -0.020 %
Dec 17 08:22:15 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.79744 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 08:22:29 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.764672 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.009 %
Dec 17 08:22:37 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.79744 MB Change: Increased, 32.768 KB, 0.009 %
Dec 17 08:22:45 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 372.690944 MB Change: Decreased, -106.496 KB, -0.029 %
....
Dec 17 08:44:46 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 381.915136 MB Change: Increased, 40.96 KB, 0.011 %
Dec 17 08:44:58 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 387.9936 MB Change: Increased, 6078.464 KB, 1.592 %
Dec 17 08:45:09 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 387.981312 MB Change: Decreased, -12.288 KB, -0.003 %
Dec 17 08:45:25 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 387.964928 MB Change: Decreased, -16.384 KB, -0.004 %
Dec 17 08:45:40 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 388.284416 MB Change: Increased, 319.488 KB, 0.082 %
Dec 17 08:45:55 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 388.440064 MB Change: Increased, 155.648 KB, 0.040 %
Dec 17 08:46:06 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 388.407296 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.008 %
Dec 17 08:46:14 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 388.358144 MB Change: Decreased, -49.152 KB, -0.013 %
Dec 17 08:46:24 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 388.325376 MB Change: Decreased, -32.768 KB, -0.008 %
Dec 17 08:46:39 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 388.3008 MB Change: Decreased, -24.576 KB, -0.006 %
....
Dec 17 09:08:33 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 405.762048 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 09:08:41 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 405.753856 MB Change: Decreased, -8.192 KB, -0.002 %
Dec 17 09:08:48 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 405.938176 MB Change: Increased, 184.32 KB, 0.045 %
Dec 17 09:09:03 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 405.880832 MB Change: Decreased, -57.344 KB, -0.014 %
Dec 17 09:09:09 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 406.011904 MB Change: Increased, 131.072 KB, 0.032 %
Dec 17 09:09:15 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 405.970944 MB Change: Decreased, -40.96 KB, -0.010 %
Dec 17 09:09:27 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 408.100864 MB Change: Increased, 2129.92 KB, 0.525 %
Dec 17 09:09:38 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 408.010752 MB Change: Decreased, -90.112 KB, -0.022 %
Dec 17 09:09:53 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 408.223744 MB Change: Increased, 212.992 KB, 0.052 %
Dec 17 09:10:08 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 408.109056 MB Change: Decreased, -114.688 KB, -0.028 %
....
Dec 17 09:31:34 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 426.8032 MB Change: Increased, 114.688 KB, 0.027 %
Dec 17 09:31:50 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 426.76224 MB Change: Decreased, -40.96 KB, -0.010 %
Dec 17 09:31:59 - MainThread - Memory usage: Total: 426.778624 MB Change: Increased, 16.384 KB, 0.004 %
```

Can someone suggest how to properly cleanup memory to avoid this memory leak ?

Comment: Reported on PyCurl GitHub repository https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/721

Comment: Have you actually run your process long enough to be pretty sure that it is actually leaking?  Use of RSS as a metric for process size is not a great idea, because a process can be quite large without having many resident pages and the set of resident pages can get smaller without the process actually shrinking when, for example, other more active processes cause those pages to be swapped out.   Try running your process overnight and see, using VSS which is still imperfect but a better metric than RSS, whether your process continues to grow.

Comment: Code attached here is test code to reproduce behavior. Actual application is an always running systemd service, application crashes after 5-7 days due to excessive memory use. Memory consumption has been confirmed from htop.

Comment: I would suspect here that if you watch the VSZ of your test code that it will stabilize after at most a few hours and that your test code will not crash.   What is the longest you have ever run your test code and did it crash in that time?  Also, does your actual application produce a core dump when it crashes?

Comment: Not the test code but actual application that is using pycurl is a systemd service. I has been observed that memory consumption of the application grows over time and eventually (almost after 5-7 days) it is killed by OS due to excessive RAM usage.

Please see the discussion here https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/721.

Comment: Moreover same code/logic works fine if I replace 'pycurl' with 'requests'.

Comment: I understand that your systemd service crashes but I was suggesting that it would be valuable to understand whether your test program actually crashes too, as part of verifying that you had reproduced the issue with the smaller program.  At this point I can understand that you might not want to bother to do that, given that you have a solution that works for you.

Comment: Update: If you run the program long enough, requests also starts showing same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Please see the discussion here https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/721

Apparently PyCurl does not play well with Python multi-threading when thread count is large enough, but works fine in single thread.
For scenarios requiring concurrent API calls it is recommended to use pycurl.CurlMulti

Recommendation: https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/721#issuecomment-992632719

Test Code: https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/721#issuecomment-994475703